# How to create a common worker when using WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-networking

I want to create a `NetworkRequestWorker` which executes a network request using `WorkManager`.

All network requests would have a similar set of logic:

- Parameters for network request (request body)
- Do something when request succeeds
- Do something when request fails

I want to abstract this functionality out so we can use same worker for making a network request.

Since you can't pass parameters to a `CoroutineWorker` I am not sure what would be the best way to abstract this out.

Also, a Worker can only take in primitive data types, one option is to serialize a class and pass it to the worker but I am thinking there might be better ways to achieve this.

Another option would be to create a new Worker class for each network request but that would lead to code duplication.

[Google's nowinandroid sample](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/feafb5fbed6fd381503ea1f3d88477558200a1ed/sync/work/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/sync/workers/SyncWorker.kt#L49) passes repositories to a worker, does that mean we can passes classes as a parameter. How do we pass an object to worker?

Comment: I didnot get what you want. But I just want to inform you that `CoroutineWorker` is a `Worker` so you can pass paramters to it via `WorkerParameters`.

Comment: @fshdn19 By parameters here i mean parameters for making a network request, this could also be request body with multiple parameters

Comment: What kind of network request do you want to execute? I don't think `WorkManager` is suitable for the case.

Comment: @fshdn19 This can be any network request for example deleting something on server, modifying something or fetching data.

Comment: So you can make a network request on your screen, e.g in viewmodel or in fragments. I don't think you should use WorkManager for that sort of cases

Comment: @fshdn19 Lacking a bit of context here as to why WorkManager is required - these network request could happen while user is offline and for an offline fist app which allows user to modify data. These requests must be made when user comes back online for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use `WorkManager` to make a regular network request, e.g., fetching data, calling an API, etc.
Because:

- It's difficult to control progress
- It's difficult to handle errors or get the response
- And the more important thing is you cannot ensure that your network request is executed immediately

You can execute a regular network request directly in your viewmodel or in your activity, fragment with coroutines and/or Retrofit. It's quietly simple and easy to control.

For example, with coroutine, you can see it [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/simplifying-apis-with-coroutines-and-flow-a6fb65338765)